# Turning on Wifi at boot-up

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

My embedded board uses Linux Kernel version 3.18.

I would like to configure my Wifi (using wpa_supplicant and then dhcpcd commands) automatically, as soon as the board boots up.

I made a shell script for the same (I verified the script by executing it manually) and placed this in "/etc/init.d" directory.
Then made a symbolic link to the shell script file in the "/etc/rc.d" directory.

However, doing this change does not serve my purpose. Can anyone please help me out.

PS: It is important to note that it takes around 3-4 seconds for my Wifi module to be inserted into the kernel once the board boots up.

Comment: *"doing this change does not serve my purpose"* -- What does that mean?  You've actually managed to come up with a summation more ambiguous than *" it doesn't work."*  At what point are you defining that the board has achieved this *"boot up"*?  BTW the *"up"* in  *"boot up"* is superfluous.  There is no "boot down" or "boot sideways".

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;
in initscript call differant script managing wpa_supplicant,dhcpd so that init-script won't block.

It is nice practice not to block in init-scripts. so you can do differed processing in init-script. i.e. start different script in background which checks module insertion and wpa_supplicant also can modify it to keep checking status. Something similar happens in Desktop Linux OS. The program name is NetworkManager.